# How can I avoid catching an Exception using an if?

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am scraping a web page and until now I was catching an `ArgumentNullException` using `try/catch`. However, I want to change the logic to using an `if`. My attempt is down below.

```
if (document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td")
        .Where(x => x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Log.html")).Any() is true) { 

        HtmlNode[] nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td")
           .Where(x => x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Log.html")).ToArray();
        if (nodes.Length > 1) {
           nodes = nodes.Where((source, index) => index != 1).ToArray();
        }
     [..........]
     } else {
        LogException("Item is null", taskId, buildId);
     }
```

But on the line:

> if (document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td")
> .Where(x => x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Log.html")).Any() is true)

I am still getting an `ArgumentNullException`. How should I write it instead?

Comment: First off you should never **catch** an `ArgumentNullException`. Instead you should **avoid** it in the first place. Apart from this where excactly does the exception occur? Which variable is null here?

Comment: You can use [when in a catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/when#when-in-a-catch-statement) statement to catch an exception only if a condition is true. It's unclear what you want though. What you posted shouldn't throw such an exception *unless* `Value` is null.  `is true` is meaningless as `Any` always returns a bool value. What is the *actual* exception? If `Value` is null, catching the exception won't help

Comment: You can use `.SelectNodes.Any(x=>...)` to shorten the expression although a far better option would be to use a proper XPath expression : `//td[contains(@title,'Log.html')]`.

Comment: When scraping the web page, sometimes the `Log.html` is missing and hence, `Value` is null and this exception is thrown. I was able to bypass it using `try/catch` before, but I figured it's not a good practice, in this case, at least. Therefore, I've been trying to do it using an `if`, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos, I will try that, instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an XPath expression to check the attribute contents as well:

```
var logs=document.DocumentNode
                 .SelectNodes("//td[contains(@title,'Log.html')]")
                 .ToArray();
if (logs.Length==0)
{
    LogException("Item is null", taskId, buildId);
} 
else if (logs.Length>1)
{
    logs=logs[1..];
}
```

The new range syntax in C#8 allows replacing

```
nodes.Where((source, index) => index != 1).ToArray();
```

with just

```
logs=logs[1..];
```

Answer (score -2):

Why not

```
 .Where(x => {
    if (x.Attributes["title"] != null) { 
       return x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Log.html")).Any();
    }
    else { 
       return false;
    }
  })
```

Comment: Does this even compile? Either `x.Attributes["title"]` returns a `bool so `x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains`` will fail to compile, or it's not a bool, in which case `x.Attributes["title"]` will fail

Comment: Sorry, to much JS and C++ where if (null) is simply handled as false... Sorry that C# is so limited.

Comment: Or a bit shorter `=> x.Attributes["title"]?.Value.Contains("Log.html").Any() == true`;

Comment: @HimBromBeere true, why don't you make your comment an awnser?

Comment: @rioki  Such techniques were only used in the previous century, when C had no real `boolean` type. Since C99, this is frowned upon. C++ good practices *strongly* discourage this too, because it leads to unexpected bugs. And JavaScript uses `===` for the same reason. This isn't a C# limitation.

Answer (score -2):

One way could be doing something like:

```
var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td");
if (nodes.Any())
{
    var logs = nodes.Where(x => x.Attributes["title"].Value.Contains("Log.html"));
    if(logs.Any())
    {
        var filterLogs = logs.Where((source, index) => index != 1).ToArray();
    }
    
}
```

Another option depending on your C# version, it's using an optional chain null [Null Conditional operator](https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/null-conditional-operator-in-c-6)

```
var result = document.DocumentNode?.SelectNodes("//td")?
    .Where(x => x.Attributes["title"].Value?.Contains("Log.html"))
```

Comment: The Null Conditional Operator is truly a life changer. Thank you!

Comment: I don't like this solution, because it evaluates deferred enumerables more than once. Evaluating a deferred enumerable can be costly, and also doing it twice can some times (not in this case) produce inconsistent results.